# RxJS5 - Observable send next message to only one of its subscribers

Tags: node.js, rxjs5

Using RxJS5, what is the best way to send the next message from an Observable to only one of its subscribers? To be more specific, I want to send the next message to the oldest subscriber in the subscribers/observers list.

Here is my attempt, but I am having trouble verifying that it's correct:

```
        let obsClient = this.obsClient = new Subject<any>();

        this.clientStream = Observable.create(sub => {

            const push = Subscriber.create(v => {
                // I assume that zeroeth element holds oldest sub
                if(push === obsClient.observers[0]){
                    sub.next(v);
                }
            });

            return obsClient.subscribe(push);
        });

        function onClientConnectionChange(clientCount) {
            obsClient.next({
                time: Date.now(),
                clientCount: clientCount
            });
        }
```

as you can see, we push to the Subject, but that is wrapped by this.clientStream. Any subscribers will subscribe to this.clientStream not this.obsClient.

Comment: Whenever I see _"constructions"_ like these (which I made myself while learning RxJS), I meanwhile usually start by looking at the rest of the application-architecture, if something is bad there - and so far I have had __not a single case__ where I had to use some weird, complicated/hard to read construction in order to solve some issue, up until now __everything__ could be solved with the existing operators and/or by fixing mistakes in the other parts of the application - and I use RxJS daily. - Probably not the answer you are looking for, that's why it is a comment and not an answer ;-)

Comment: @olsn you are like the 4th person to tell me that what I am doing is crazy :) at some point I may have to accept it. However, we can see with 2 lines of code that we can notify only the oldest subscriber. It's a nice feature. Feel free to weigh in - https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2312

Comment: @olsn in short - Observables fit the observer pattern. Sometimes in the observer pattern we don't want to notify all observers. That. Is. All. ;)

Comment: If anyone can offer a more RxJS-y way of doing this, then great, but either way I need functionality like this.

Comment: I understand your problem, but it is not really the idea of the basic Observable Pattern - the basic pattern is: "Either you subscribe and get data, or you don't subscribe and don't get data" - maybe you could have the first subscriber subscribe to a different stream? Anyhow: A huge issue I have in my mind: The next guy, that has to debug some related observer-issue, will go crazy(and maybe even ballistic) after finding out why not all observers receive all data - so for the sake of your own health: Don't. ;-P

Comment: hmmm a couple comments would make it clear what's going on - also this is for a library not application so. I think the Observer pattern is not always about notifying all observers. You could just change it so each subscriber subscribes on a different channel. But I need to keep track of which is the oldest subscriber!

Comment: * a couple comments in the codebase

Comment: So do you want the rest of the Observers to see completion and error messages? What is the point of keeping the other Observers around if you aren't sending messages to them?

Comment: @paulpdaniels because the other observers will receive messages in the future, they are merely in line to see messages, once the oldest observer unsubscribes. I don't need the other observers to see completion or error messages for the oldest observer.